# Adding an "and" to the last word in String - js/Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this solved, but I am looking to see if there is a **better way** to do this.  Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/143h9wrq/ So what I do is check to see if there are 2+ Ids, then turn the string into an array, take the last array item and add 'and ', put it back together and display it.

I am looking to see if there is a better way to condense that if.  I am using Angular in the project, not in the example.  Basicly listArr would be $scope.listArr and issues is $user.issues.

JS:

```
var issuesId =[1,2,3,4]
var issues = "issue one, issue two, issue three, issue four";

if (issuesId.length >= 2) {
  var str = issues.split(', ');
  var addAnd = str.pop();
  addAnd = 'and ' + addAnd;
  str.push(addAnd);
  var listArr = str.join(', ');
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = listArr;
}
else {
  var listArr = issues;
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = listArr;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p>{{listArr}}</p>
```

Comment: I think your approach is more than valid

Comment: The only problem I see with your approach is that you end up with a sentence that is not correct as it will insert a `,` before the `and` when none is needed.

Comment: This question is tagged under `angularjs` - And that approach is nothing like an angularjs approach

Comment: I think it's because the code is used in Angular but the jsfiddle is not so the code displayed is the one from jsfiddle instead of the angular code. I imagine in the angular code the value is just assigned to `listArr` on the scope.

Comment: Maybe your particular use case requires a comma with only two items but this is usually incorrect.

Comment: This is a bit more simplified. https://jsfiddle.net/143h9wrq/1/

Comment: @blessem Nice solution, better/shorter, but when I join them I need  commas added in between the text.  When I put the comma in the join I get a comma before and after the and.

Comment: @RooksStrife https://jsfiddle.net/143h9wrq/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortest solution will be with regular expressions:

```
var s = "a, b, c";

s.replace(/ ([^,]*)$/, " and $1"); // "a, b, and c"
```

or:

```
s.replace(/, ([^,]*)$/, " and $1"); // "a, b and c"
```

Comment: This is perfect thanks.  If you have time, would you mind putting a brief overview on what does what.  I have used RegEx before and love https://regex101.com/, but always forget what does what :]

Answer (score 3):

Why not change the last element of the array, directly from the array, without poping and pushing it back again, like this: `str[str.length - 1] = 'and ' + str[str.length - 1]`?

I've also trimmed down a bunch of code lines:

```
var issuesId = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var issues = "issue one, issue two, issue three, issue four";

var listArr = issues;

if (issuesId.length >= 2) {
    var str = issues.split(', ');
    str[str.length - 1] = 'and ' + str[str.length - 1];
    listArr = str.join(', ');
}

document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = listArr;
```

Answer (score 0):

More functional style. Try this:

```
var issuesId =[1,2,3,4]
var issues = "issue one, issue two, issue three, issue four";

if(issuesId.length >= 2){
  var arr = issues.split(',');

  arr = arr.map(function(phrase, index){
    if(index < arr.length - 1)
     phrase+=' and';
    return phrase;
  })
  issues = arr.join(', ');
}

console.log(issues);
```

http://codepen.io/gpincheiraa/pen/bpLJdv

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I'd wrap the string manipulation into a function, separating it from the actual dom manipulation:

```
function mkStr(issues) {
   var delimeter = ', ';
   if (issues.length < 2) {
      return issues;
   } else {
     let parts = issues.split(delimeter);
     let last = "and " + parts.pop();
     parts.push(last);
     return parts.join(delimeter);
   }
}

document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = mkStr(issues);

mkStr("a, b, c"); // "a, b, and c"
```

But, maybe, you want rather to have "a, b, and c" as an output - this would be more natural somehow. Then you could do something like this:

```
function mkStr2(issues) {
   var delimeter = ', ';
   if (issues.length < 2) {
      return issues;
   } else {
     let parts = issues.split(delimeter);
     let last = parts.pop();
     return parts.join(delimeter) +
            " and " +
            last;
   }
}

mkStr2("a, b, c"); // "a, b, and c"
```